# Can we write IF statement without else in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, if-statement, conditional-statements

I wrote some code to create an simple todo app in angular js. I have the following function code to remove the tasks from the list.

**Javascript code**

```
$scope.deleteTask =  function(){
    $scope.tasks.splice(this.$index, 1);
    if($scope.tasks.length < 1){
        $scope.noTask = true;
    }     
};
```

**HTML code**

```
    <li ng-repeat="task in tasks track by $index">{{task}}  <button ng- click="deleteTask()">x</button></li> </li>
    <p ng-show="noTask">No Tasks Available </p>
```

I wanted to show a message when there are no tasks in the list. i have achieved this using "if" statement. but i don't need an else here. i am not sure whether its the right way. what will be the proper way to achieve this

Comment: What is not working ? Looks good....

Comment: The `else` part of an if-statement is optional. Your code is correct.

Comment: it is working fine. but can i write a "if" statement without "else". is it a good practice? @RayonDabre

Comment: of course it's good. Did you consider googling that before posting it here? It should be explained in a lot of places.

Comment: It is perfectly fine.. But I would initialize `$scope.noTask = something` initially...depending on the length of the `$scope.tasks`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code.
You can use the `if` statement without the `else`.
In your case I would recommend writing it as follows to remove some unnecessary code:

```
<p ng-show="tasks.length==0">No Tasks Available </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

As in any *(?)* other programming language you can omit `else` part if it's empty.

Just make sure that if you assign some value in `if (true)` than if it's not executed have default value for that variable:

```
var test = false;

if (Math.rand() < 0.5) {
    test = true;
}
```

Also there is `shorthand` for if else (where you can't omit `else` part):

```
var test = Math.rand() < 0.5 ? "True value" : "False value";
```

Comment: As a note, in some expression oriented languages like OCaml the `else` clause is **mandatory**

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to show a message when there are no tasks in the list. i have achieved this using "if" statement. but i don't need an else here. i am not sure whether its the right way. what will be the proper way to achieve this

You don't need an `else` statement, you can use `ng-if`.

The `ng-if` statement is also available without an `else` condition.

You should be able to use this angular code:

```
$scope.deleteTask =  function(){
    $scope.tasks.splice(this.$index, 1);
};
```

And this part for the HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="task in tasks track by $index">{{task}}  
     <button ng-click="deleteTask()">x</button>
</li>
<p ng-show="noTask" ng-if="tasks.length == 0">No Tasks Available </p>
```